# SiC MOSFET SPICE model not behaving properly

Tags: mosfet, simulation, ltspice

I have been trying to simulate a fully controlled full bridge using SiC MOSFETs and so far haven't gettng at least expected results. So I tried to check what is happening using a single MOSFET and a simple circuit like this -
[image: Simple MOSFET driving circuit]

However, when I run the simulation, the current through the resistor looks like this -

[image: Current through MOSFET/resistor]

I need to uderstand what I am doing wrong while simulating this circuit.
1. Does the gate need a resistor in series ?
2. The floating terminals of the MOSFET are Tj and Tc (temperatures) I have assumed that they can be kept floating.

**Update-**
Zoomed in waveform -
[image: zoomed waveform of one apparent pulse]
Edit -
The MOSFET is rated at 1200V and 90A. The simulation works fine up until Vds as ~55V. Thereafter it breaks down and shows these similar results for any voltage above ~55V

Comment: zoom in on one of those switching events--- use 1` nanosecond/division

Comment: @analogsystemsrf updated the question

Comment: I've had a similar experience trying to solve this problem recently and had to stop before i found a solution so i'd be interested in the result of this question too.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the library? Only for this device. While I'm not saying this is the case, it could be that the model is not that good, or that it needs special SPICE considerations.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I downloaded the model from Wolfspeed/CREE's website and I'm skeptical about it being shared here because it required user signup. The website is [go.wolfspeed.com](http://go.wolfspeed.com)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I updated the question mentioned that the simulation breaks down when Vds is greater than ~55V. Up until that it works fine.

Comment: @shreyas If anyone else is willing to sign in simply to download an archive, and is willing to help afterwards, I wish you the best of luck. Please note I am not pointing the finger at you, but at any site that does that -- if you're going to allow users to use your models, don't force them to give you personal data, you'd only be gaining more users to use your models. Personal opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not giving the results you're expecting is because of your second assumption.

> 2. The floating terminals of the MOSFET are Tj and Tc (temperatures) I have assumed that they can be kept floating.

The Cree C2M SiC MOSFET PSPICE MODEL Quick start guide REV 1.8 (which was available when I downloading all of the spice models in one zip-file some time ago) specifies the following

> The Junction Temperature terminal (Tj) can either be used to read junction
>   temperature or to fix junction temperature. **This terminal can be left floating.**
>
> The Case Temperature terminal (Tc) must be connected to either a voltage
>   source or a Heat Sink RC Network. **This terminal should not be left floating.**

The reason is that the electrical and thermal circuits of the model are connected through the device equations. This is true for most SPICE models of semiconductors.

I connected a dc voltage source to the Tc terminal and managed to successfully simulate your circuit in LTSpice IV.

Note: Due to the discontinuities in the models from Cree/Wolfspeed (and others), it is often necessary to modify the simulation tolerances to get the simulation to converge.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like it is super easy to miss. Answer accpeted.

Comment: @hooksworks In case you have missed it