# Simulation of boost converter using SiC MOSFET in LTspice

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, boost

[image]I am trying to simulate boost converter using SiC MOSFET (MOSFET MODEL = G2R1000MT17D). The boost converter specifications are:

1. Vin = 200 V
2. Vout = 400 V
3. Fsw = 150 kHz

When simulating the above converter my simulation is not running. Kindly help me to figure out where I am going wrong[![LTspice schematic][2]][2]

Comment: Where is your V(out) node?

Comment: Hi andy thanks for asking  The Vout node is across the resistor 320 ohm.

Comment: I think you would change ... .options abstol=0.1 (? absolute tolerance on voltage = 0.1 V) ...    .IC v(vout)=400 (ok)   ...  and add .IC i(L1)=2.5 ...  .tran 0 5m  -- proceed by little step time (5 ms,   max internal step 1ns) save intermediary results and continue simulation ... it works for me with microcap v12.

Comment: Sure Antonio i will try and let you know

Comment: @Vengatesh The reason Andy asked about `V(out)` is because you have an `.IC` condition for a node named `OUT`, but there's no such label attached, anywhere. Therefore your `.IC` has no effect. Try ading `ic=380` to the capacitor, maybe also `rser=10m`. It might help to add `rser=10m rpar=10k` to the inductor, `rser=10m cpar=1m` to the voltage source, add a capacitor across the SiC with `100p rser=100`. There's not much else to do since the library that I have (from genesicsemi.com, Cree needs registration) is encrypted.

Comment: Those `.opt` that you use are a bit questionable, they are much too relaxed. Try the alternate solver, too (*Control Panel > SPICE > Solver* drop-down menu).

Comment: Hii  @concerned citizen I tried the simulation and made the changes but still the simulation is not running. But when I used the CREE WOLFSPEED (Sic MOSFET)  instead of GenSemi (Sic MOSFET) the simulation is running perfectly without any flaw.

Comment: I also changed my schematic and updated. Kindly have a look at the above schematic . Let me know if any glitch in it  The simulation is now running but only for some 70 to 100 Nano seconds and after that the simulation is not running. I don't know what to do. This glitch is occurring only when I use GenSemi Sic MOSFET .

Comment: @Vengatesh   See also this post (for explanation about your SiC MOSFET about wires Tc and Tj :  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/462681/sic-mosfet-spice-model-not-behaving-properly?rq=1 I did not know these models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my simulations about "starting" behavior.

UJ3C120080K3S for SiC (1200V 8A) and 6EWH06FN-E (600V 6A) for diode (should be changed). I will update ...  diode voltage too low. Changed for a 1200 V. Peaks are same.

You can see that there is (ok, there are short ... but not negligible when choosing devices ...) important peaks of voltage of capacitor and current of inductor. (Can be "avoided" or "admissible" by an "intelligent starting" phase, duty cycle = ~ 5%, then increased progressively until what is needed)

[image]

NB : Simulation done at 200 kHz (duty cycle = 50 %)

For stationary picture, add : .ic v(Vc) 400   and .ic i(L1) 2.5  ...

[image]